# Continuation token not visible while browsing API

Tags: api, azure-devops

Continuation token is not coming while browsing below API for azure DevOps to get the project related information. It is showing data for initial 500 users only... To browse the next page, no continuation token is available. Though it is coming in Postman.... I am solving the problem using python code.... So I need continuation token programitically:

[https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/_apis/graph/users?scopeDescriptor={project_descriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7BORG%7D/_apis/graph/users?scopeDescriptor=%7Bproject_descriptor%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.1)

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69285731/274535